# Expo sqlite foreign key

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

Did anyone work on react native expo's sqlite database with foreign key constraints? Can we use structure similar to sql?

I'm trying to work on it building multiple tables with foreign key condition.

Example: If we have 2 tables Persons and Orders where personID is referred as foreign key in orders table. How would it be done using sqlite?

Answer (score 3):

You would have two tables, perhaps with a column as the alias of the **rowid** column, this

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    personid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    personname TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    orderid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ordername TEXT, 
    person_reference INTEGER REFERENCES persons(personid)
);
```

- **Note** that you have to turn foreign key handling on e.g. by executing `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` (or true). See [PRAGMA foreign_keys](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys)
- in SQLite coding `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` defines that column as an alias of the [**rowid** column](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), and if a value is not provided for the column when inserting then an integer value will be assigned. The initial value for the first row will be 1, subsequent values will ***typically*** be 1 greater than the highest rowid value (read the link above in regards why the word typically has been used).

If you then try to insert an Order for a non-existent personid you will then get a Foreign Key conflict.

An alternative to the column level definition would be to define the foreign key(s) at the table level e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    orderid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    ordername TEXT, 
    person_reference INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY (person_reference) REFERENCES persons(personid)
);
```

As an example, consider the following :-

```
INSERT INTO persons (personname) VALUES 
    ('Fred'),
    ('Mary'),
    ('Sue'),
    ('Tom')
;
INSERT INTO orders (ordername, person_reference) VALUES
    ('Order 1 for Fred',1),
    ('Order 2 for Sue',3),
    ('Order 3 for Fred',1),
    ('Order 4 for Mary',2)
;   
INSERT into orders (ordername, person_reference) VALUES
    ('Order 5 for nobody',100);
```

The result would be :-

> ```
> INSERT INTO persons (personname) VALUES ('Fred'),('Mary'),('Sue'),('Tom')
> > Affected rows: 4
> > Time: 0.453s
>
>
> INSERT INTO orders (ordername, person_reference) VALUES
>   ('Order 1 for Fred',1),('Order 2 for Sue',3),('Order 3 for Fred',1),('Order 4 for Mary',2)
> > Affected rows: 4
> > Time: 0.084s
>
>
> INSERT into orders (ordername, person_reference) VALUES
>   ('Order 5 for nobody',100)
> > FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
> > Time: 0s
> ```

i.e. the last as there is no row in the persons table with a personid of 100, then the last insert (on it's own doe demonstration) fails.

You may wish to refer to [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: Foreign keys on needs to be done outside of a transaction: (you can check `error === null`) `db.exec([{ sql: 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;', args: [] }], false, (error, resultSet) => {});`

Comment: BTW: I would say defining after column list is the main definition, column level is the alternative - on table level is in the main example in docs - https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html and also column level can't be used when you want to define compound (2+) primary key columns as reference `FOREIGN KEY(x,y) REFERENCES parentTable)` however works